# Python using Popen to grab terminal output and print line with keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am creating a function that will return the line output of my Popen with my keywords that I have set.

Code i have so far:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["sudo dosfsck -w -r -l -v -a {}".format(mountpoint)], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
keywords = "difference" #want to add to this list. Create an array? 
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if keyword in line:
        print(line)
        return line
```

How can I add multiple keywords that I want to monitor and print/return the lines associated with those keywords?

Comment: Did you consider a regular expression?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I am new to python, in bash i would usually use the logical OR, does python support this in variables?

Comment: It does, but it may be simpler to use a regular expression, since the output of most commands follows a predictable pattern.